# Would certain questions about contemporary church leaders be on-topic for C.SE purposes?

Tags: discussion, scope

It has already been established that questions about historic church leaders can be on-topic, if they are in keeping with the other guidelines for germane content. **Would similarly-scoped questions regarding noteworthy contemporary teachers be on-topic as well?**

Here's an example question:

> John Piper is the well known and highly regarded (and recently retired) Pastor for Preaching and Teaching at Bethlehem Church in Minnesota, and the leader of [Desiring God Ministries](http://www.desiringgod.org/). Piper is widely recognized for his ability to teach, and he has contributed significantly to the revitalization of the Reformed faith that has taken place in the American church in recent decades.
>
> I recently heard it said that he does not subscribe to all five of the "Main Points of Doctrine" in the [Canons of Dordt](http://www.reformed.org/documents/canons_of_dordt.html), popularly known as the five points of Calvinism, or "T.U.L.I.P." -- specifically, that he does not agree with limited atonement.
>
> Is this true? If so, where has he said so online?

Comment: Nevermind, already answered as on-topic here: http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1406/4786